Extra pair of parenthesis in tikz plot
I'm using a \foreach loop to plot the following picture, but there is an extra pair of parenthesis at the position of (3). I've tried to use different compilers and all gave the same mysterious plot.

Here's my code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (O) at (3.5, -1.5) {(0)};
    
    \foreach \x/\val in {
        0/2, 
        1/3, 
        2/5, 
        3/7, 
        4/11, 
        5/13, 
        6/17, 
    } {
        \node[] (A) at (\x, 0) {(\val)};
        \draw[thick] (A) -- (O);
    }
    
    \node[] (x) at (7, 0) {$\cdots$};
    \draw[thick] (x) -- (O);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


It seems that empty values in coordinates are read as 1:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thin, dashed] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \draw (0,0) node[below]{(0,0)} (1,1) node[above]{(1,1)};
  \draw[thick, -] (0,0) -- (,);% empty values
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


So, simply remove the last comma in
\foreach \x/\val in {
    0/2,
    1/3,
    2/5,
    3/7,
    4/11,
    5/13,
    6/17% no comma for the last pair
}

Example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (O) at (3.5, -1.5) {(0)};

    \foreach \x/\val in {
        0/2,
        1/3,
        2/5,
        3/7,
        4/11,
        5/13,
        6/17% no comma for the last pair
    } {
        \node[] (A) at (\x, 0) {(\val)};
        \draw[thick] (A) -- (O);
    }

    \node[] (x) at (7, 0) {$\cdots$};
    \draw[thick] (x) -- (O);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Interesting! I wonder why the extra comma produces the extra parentheses. It seems like \x gets set to 1 and \val to nothing.

@MatthewLeingang I did a fast test (see my edit), it seems that empty values in coordinates are read as 1.
